# How to create a list of dictionaries from another list of dictionaries by taking only some keys : python

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

How to convert a list of dictionaries `[{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}, {"a":4, "b":5, "c":4}]` to `[{"a":1}, {"a":4}]`. I wrote a function to just pop the keys that are not required by looping through the list.

```
def pop_keys(dictionary, keys_to_pop):
   for item in dictionary:
        for key in keys_to_pop:
            item.pop(key, None)
   return dictionary
```

Is there any better and fastest way to achieve the same.?

Comment: It is a list of dictionaries

Comment: Do you need the same dict objects mutated in-place or are fresh new dicts acceptable?

Comment: @Pynchia I need the same dict

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
l1 = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}, {"a":4, "b":5, "c":4}]
keys_to_pop = {"b", "c"} # use a set for fast lookup
l2 = [{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k not in keys_to_pop} for d in l1] # use comprehension list and dictionary
```

Comment: Check if he wants the same dict objects, mutated in -place